# Wordpress: How to prevent sub-categories from showing in custom taxonomies?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, children, custom-taxonomy

I've created a custom taxonomy, a custom post type and a custom page.
The issue: Wordpress show all posts that are part of the category AND all its sub-categories. This is the code of custom page:

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query->set('post_type', $postType);
$wp_query->set('orderby', $orderBy);
$wp_query->set('order', 'ASC');
$wp_query->set('posts_per_page', 12);
$active_term = get_term_by('slug', $term, $taxonomy);
if ($active_term->parent == 0)
{


    $terms = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
        'hide_empty' => false,
        'parent' => $active_term->term_id,
        'orderby' => 'term_id',
        'order' => 'ASC'
    ) );
    $slug_array = array();
    if( count($terms) > 0 )
    {
        foreach ($terms as $t){
            $slug_array[] = $t->slug;
        }
        $the_slug = $terms[0]->slug;

        $active_title = $terms[0]->name;
    }
    else
    {
        $the_slug = $active_term->slug;
        $slug_array = array($the_slug);
        $active_title = $active_term->name;
    }
    $tax_query = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $slug_array,
            'include_children' => false
        )
    );

}
else
{

    $tax_query = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array ( $active_term->slug ),
            'include_children' => false
        )
    );
    $the_slug = $active_term->slug;
    $active_title = $active_term->name;
}
$wp_query->set('tax-query', $tax_query);
$wp_query->get_posts();
```

As you see, the option 'include_children' => false is set and Wordpres keeps showing all children. I don't know what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is exactly the code thats live, then you might (i say might, 'cause it did not test this) have a typo in your code

`$wp_query->set('tax-query', $tax_query);`

should be

`$wp_query->set('tax_query', $tax_query);`

> notice the underscore instead of a hyphen.

See also [WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

Comment: Thank you, very much. It works! but, in addition. I had to comment between:
 /* if ($active_term->parent == 0) and else { */   $tax_query = array(

Comment: Thank you, very much. It works! but, in addition. I had to comment between:
 /* if ($active_term->parent == 0) and else { */   $tax_query = array(

and the previous line to $wp_query->set('tax-query', $tax_query);
// }

Apologies for the repeated comment, but I can´t edit the same comment after 5 minutes.